# Как конвертировать единичное значение long в массив unsigned char?

Tags: c++, c++11

Грубо говоря нужен метод конвертации единиченого значения типа `long` (Signed 64-bit integer согласно спецификации) в массив байт (`unsigned char[]` для C++).

Таблица для проверки контрольных значений (т.е. что должно получиться в итоге):

```
//                     long                    byte array
//                     ----                    ----------
//                        0       00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
//                 16777215       FF-FF-FF-00-00-00-00-00
//                -16777215       01-00-00-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF
//               1000000000       00-CA-9A-3B-00-00-00-00
//              -1000000000       00-36-65-C4-FF-FF-FF-FF
//               4294967296       00-00-00-00-01-00-00-00
//              -4294967296       00-00-00-00-FF-FF-FF-FF
//          187649984473770       AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-00-00
//         -187649984473770       56-55-55-55-55-55-FF-FF
//      1000000000000000000       00-00-64-A7-B3-B6-E0-0D
//     -1000000000000000000       00-00-9C-58-4C-49-1F-F2
//     -9223372036854775808       00-00-00-00-00-00-00-80
//      9223372036854775807       FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-7F
```

**Проблема. При таком методе проверки отрицательные числа показывают неверный результат!!!**:

```
long x = -1000000000; // 00-36-65-C4-FF-FF-FF-FF
unsigned char *s = (unsigned char *)&x;

for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    printf("%X\r\n", s[i]);
}
```

Это проблема метода проверки или самой функции конвертации из ответа ниже?

Comment: Не очень понимаю, а что именно Вас не устраивает? Вывод соответствует таблице вроде.

Comment: @alexolut, смотрите, число: `-1000000000` должно дать результат: `00-36-65-C4-FF-FF-FF-FF`, а по факту дает такой результат: `00-36-65-C4-00-00-00-00`

Comment: [`00-36-65-C4-FF-FF-FF-FF`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/f5Sn4W5bIaVRFgZl)

Comment: @alexolut, у меня VS 2013, проект x64 разрядный, консольное приложение под отладкой, дает такой результат, который я написал.

Comment: Тьху. А с чего Вы решили, что размер `long` 8 байт? Цикл должен быть до `sizeof(x)`. Всё, что вне этого диапазона - уже мусорное значение. Если хотите увидеть `FF` используйте `long long`, но правильнее будет использовать вовсе `std::int64_t` из `<cstdint>`. [Пруф](http://rextester.com/IYMW50779)

Comment: @Alexis Посмотрите, чему равен `sizeof(long)` и удивитесь :)

Comment: @alexolut. Я пришел в нативный мир плюсов - с дотнета. Там длина типа long = 8 байт, проверить можно так: var size = sizeof(long);

Comment: Спасибо всем, не обессудьте, ошибку понял.

Comment: @alexolut: Сорри, не увидел вашего комментария перед ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно по идее так:

```
long x = -1000000000; // 00-36-65-C4-FF-FF-FF-FF
unsigned char *s = (unsigned char *)&x;

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x); i++) // sizeof(x) вместо 8
{
    printf("%02X\r\n", s[i]);
}
```

На моей VS 2015 выдаёт (как под target x86, так и x64)

```
00
36
65
C4
```

Заодно видим, что `sizeof(long) == 4` под MSVC.

---

Правильный ответ дали в комментариях до меня @alexolut и @Harry.

Answer (score 3):

Ловите

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void
reverse (char *s, int n)
{
  int i = 0;

  for (--n; i < n; i++, n--) {
    char t = s[i];
    s[i] = s[n];
    s[n] = t;
  }
}

void
print (uint64_t v)
{
  int i = 1;
  char *litte_endian = (char *)&i, // например, x86 (иначе, м.б. ARM или Sparc)
  // Про порядок байт в словах можно почитать в https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness
    *t = (char *)&v;

  if (!*litte_endian)
    reverse(t, sizeof(v));
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(v); i++)
    printf("%02x%s", (unsigned char)t[i], i < sizeof(v) - 1 ? "-" : "");
}


//                        0       00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
//                 16777215       FF-FF-FF-00-00-00-00-00
//                -16777215       01-00-00-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF
//               1000000000       00-CA-9A-3B-00-00-00-00
//              -1000000000       00-36-65-C4-FF-FF-FF-FF
//               4294967296       00-00-00-00-01-00-00-00
//              -4294967296       00-00-00-00-FF-FF-FF-FF
//          187649984473770       AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-00-00
//         -187649984473770       56-55-55-55-55-55-FF-FF
//      1000000000000000000       00-00-64-A7-B3-B6-E0-0D
//     -1000000000000000000       00-00-9C-58-4C-49-1F-F2
//     -9223372036854775808       00-00-00-00-00-00-00-80
//      9223372036854775807       FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-7F

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int i;
  int64_t a[] = {
    0,
    16777215,
    -16777215,
    1000000000,
    -1000000000,
    4294967296,
    -4294967296,
    187649984473770,
    -187649984473770,
    1000000000000000000,
    -1000000000000000000,
    -9223372036854775808,
    9223372036854775807,
  };

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++)
    print(a[i]), puts("");

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Раз метка C++11, то транслируем g++ и запускаем

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ -O3 -std=c++11 p.c && ./a.out 
p.c:61:6: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned
     -9223372036854775808,
      ^
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
ff-ff-ff-00-00-00-00-00
01-00-00-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff
00-ca-9a-3b-00-00-00-00
00-36-65-c4-ff-ff-ff-ff
00-00-00-00-01-00-00-00
00-00-00-00-ff-ff-ff-ff
aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-00-00
56-55-55-55-55-55-ff-ff
00-00-64-a7-b3-b6-e0-0d
00-00-9c-58-4c-49-1f-f2
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-80
ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-7f
End
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ uname -a && g++ --version
Linux avp-ubu1 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
g++.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Comment: Хм, а как работает `!*litte_endian`?

Comment: @VladD, смотрит что в младшем (с меньшим адресом) байте -- 0 - big, 1 - little. У ТС написан ответ для little, поэтому в big архитектуре для печати такой же таблицы надо крутить.

Comment: Подождите, а что будет для значения 0xffff00000000ffff или наоборот 0x0000ffffffff0000?

Comment: @VladD, то же что и с 0000000000000000 или ffffffffffffffff -- реверсируется само в себя. А что тут удивляет?

Comment: Окей, тогда 0xff112233445566ff? Я имею в виду, как определение big/little endian сработает? Ведь `*little_endian` будет в любом случае `0xff`.

Comment: @VladD, там little определяется кодом: `int i = 1; char *little = (char*)&i;` тестируем `i = 1`, а не `v`, которое печатаем.

Comment: А, понял, хитро, да.

Comment: @avp, для работы с big/little endian есть подходящие классы, но ваш ответ навёл на мысль использовать проверочный i в качестве индекса байт. На любой машине выводит байты в порядке возрастания адреса:
`void f(long v) {
    long i = 0x03020100;
    char *id = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i);
    for(int n = 0; n < sizeof(long); ++n) {
        std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&v)[id[n]];
    }
}
`